# Left handed equivalent of apply in Scala

Tags: scala, matrix, operator-overloading, operators

It's very easy to define something like a 2 dimensional Matrix class in Scala with an apply method that would let me elegantly access the values inside my Matrix. Quite simply one would do this :

```
class Matrix(val n: Int, val m: Int, val default: Double = 0) {
  val data: Array[Array[Double]] = Array.fill(n, m)(default)
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Double = data(x)(y)
}
```

This allows me to access elements in my matrix like so :

```
val matrix = new Matrix(3, 3)
println(matrix(2, 2))
```

What I'm after, however, is the ability to do the opposite, and actually assign values to a matrix using similar notation. Essentially I want the ability to write something like this :

```
matrix(2, 2) = 5
```

Is there any way to do this in Scala ? In C++ this is doable by overloading the parenthesis operator to return a reference rather than a copy (the former defines the setter and the latter the getter), and similarly in Python this is the distinction between the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` magic methods (with the slight difference of applying to square brackets instead of parenthesis). Does Scala support such behavior or am I stuck having to either directly access the `data` member and/or just writing a setter function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `Array`#`update` as example:

```scala
  /** Update the element at given index.
   *
   *  Note the syntax `xs(i) = x` is a shorthand for `xs.update(i, x)`.
   *
   *  @param    i   the index
   *  @param    x   the value to be written at index `i`
   */
  def update(i: Int, x: T): Unit
```

Try implementing an `update`:

```scala
class Matrix(val n: Int, val m: Int, val default: Double = 0) {
  ...
  def update(x:Int, y: Int, value: Double): Unit =
   ???
}


matrix(2,2) = 5d
```

EDIT:
You can actually use:

- `def update(x:Int, y: Int, value: Double): Unit`

instead of:

- `def update(coord: (Int,Int), value: Double): Unit`.

and get exactly the syntax you desired.

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly what I was looking for. Though you have an extra set of parenthesis in your last line ;)

Comment: With my last update you can drop the extra parenthesis

Comment: Yep that's what I just implemented in my code. Thanks again ! Pleased to see Scala supports this directly.